# Making a self-study database form (pt. 2) need help selecting a table via list choice

Tags: database, list, vba, ms-access, random

I have 37 tables in my database. I named each table using a number (1-37).
I have 37 items in my list box. The column is bound to the numbered set (1-37).

I would like to take the value from the selected choice in the list and use it to pull up the corresponding table which has questions and answers for a specific topic (irrelevant at this point).

Using the code below I get runtime error 2001 (You canceled previous operation).  I use a button to display the random question selected by the code (which worked prior to my list selection attempt).

```
txtQuestion = DLookup("Question", List18.Value, "ID = " & randomID)
```

Adding a message box with the List18.Value shows me I am selecting the correct numbers. Im unsure of what to do.

Could anyone throw me some advice? Anything would be appreciated. 
I use Access 2003 and am very new to it.

Comment: Is that DlookUp returning a null? You can test using the immediate window and the actual values.

Comment: The immediate window: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa219081(v=office.10).aspx Please report your results.

Comment: Can you upload a copy of our DB onto a file hosting site and then post the link?

Answer (score 0):

Try testing your expression in the Immediate Window:

`? DLookup("Question", List18.Value, "ID = " & randomID)`